# TypeError at /saml2/ls/post/ Not a logout_response

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-saml2-auth

I am trying to setup django with saml2 for sso with okta. In okta settings I have

```
Single Logout URL: http://localhost:8000/saml2/ls/post/
SP Issuer : http://localhost:8000/saml2/metadata/
```

as per the [documentation](https://djangosaml2.readthedocs.io/contents/miscellanea.html#okta-federation). In my settings.py I have the example config shown in the okta example, and have the `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/home'` and the 'home' path exists and works.

When I login using `http://localhost:8000/saml2/login/`, I am correctly signed in (the `saml_session` cookie is created), but I am redirected to `http://localhost:8000/saml2/ls/post/` and shown the error: `TypeError at /saml2/ls/post/ Not a logout_response`.

Does anyone have any suggestions? The redirect url is not being accessed and/or the login is triggering a logout and I am not sure how to proceed!

Thank you!